# How to edit replication factor when Debezium creates a new topic

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am using kafka-connect + Debezium to capture data changes in my MySQL cluster. Currently we use Debezium's `table.whitelist` to ingest only a very small subset of tables in that MySQL cluster. Whenever I add a new table to the `table.whitelist` config, Debezium will create a new kafka topic that only uses `replication_factor = 2` and `partition=1`. My Kafka cluster has a total of 4 brokers (1 leader and 3 followers) and in my `/opt/kafka-connect/worker.properties` file I have set the following:

- `offset.storage.replication.factor=4`
- `config.storage.replication.factor=4`
- `status.storage.replication.factor=4`

This results in me having to manually re-balance the topic every time I add a new table and it gets old real fast. [image] The last entry is the new MySQL table that was recently added, notice that it is replicated on 2 brokers while the other topics are replicated on 3.

Am I editing the wrong config file or using the wrong settings? Please halp!

Below is my Debezium config

```
{
  "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
  "snapshot.locking.mode": "none",
  "max.queue.size": "300000",
  "tasks.max": "8",
  "database.history.consumer.sasl.jaas.config": "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required   username=\"<USER>\"   password=\"<PASSWORD>\";",
  "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbhistory_mysql",
  "database.history.consumer.ssl.truststore.password": "<PASSWORD>",
  "database.history.consumer.security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
  "database.history.consumer.ssl.truststore.location": "/PATH/TO/TRUSTSTORE.jks",
  "table.whitelist": "schema.table1,schema.table2,schema.table3,schema.table4,schema.table5",
  "decimal.handling.mode": "string",
  "database.history.kafka.recovery.poll.interval.ms": "30000",
  "database.history.producer.sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN",
  "database.history.producer.sasl.jaas.config": "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required   username=\"<USER>\"   password=\"<PASSWORD>\";",
  "database.user": "debezium",
  "database.server.id": "123",
  "database.history.producer.security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
  "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "broker1.com:9092,broker2.com:9092,broker3.com:9092,broker4.com:9092",
  "database.history.producer.ssl.truststore.location": "/PATH/TO/TRUSTSTORE.jks",
  "database.server.name": "mysql",
  "database.port": "3306",
  "database.serverTimezone": "US/Pacific",
  "database.history.producer.ssl.truststore.password": "<PASSWORD>",
  "database.hostname": "mysql.cluster.amazonaws.com",
  "database.password": "<PASSWORD>",
  "name": "mysql-connector",
  "max.batch.size": "20480",
  "database.history.consumer.sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN"
}
```

Comment: Can you add your connector configuration in the question?

Comment: @AchyutVyas do you mean `worker.properties` or the debezium configs?

Comment: debezium config

Comment: @AchyutVyas I have edited my original post to include the Debezium config

Comment: Check my answer, you have to add this in your debezium connector config (sidenote: you have specified **tasks.max =8**, so is it running 8 tasks or only 1?)

Answer (score 1):

Those three properties are internal Connect topics, not auto created user topics.

For auto-created topics (which is recommended to have disabled), you set default partition and replication factors in the broker server.properties

```
num.partitions
default.replication.factor
```

I believe these are also dynamic variables that can be overriden using `kafka-configs` tooling... Maybe with `--alter --entity-type brokers --entity-default`... But probably easier to reason about if the property is actually in a config file

Answer (score 1):

You can specify topics replication factor and partition count in debezium configuration

[Ref](https://debezium.io/blog/2020/09/15/debezium-auto-create-topics/)

### Ex

add below line in your debezium connector config

```
"topic.creation.default.replication.factor": "3",
"topic.creation.default.partitions": "60"
```